# wrong output in sorting a list of list in python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have this sample list of list:

```
[[0.7578684, 'Yes, import function which lets you load items'],[1.7032554, 'Use the Test tools to edit'], [0.58279467, 'Yes, use the Designer UI Import feature to restore content from the JSON file.']]
```

I want to sort this `list` in `descending order` based on the `integer` value in each `list`. I wrote these lines but I am getting wrong output:

```
sorted_answer = answer.sort(key=lambda x: float(x[0]),reverse = True)
print(sorted_answer)
```

When I execute this I get `None` as output for `sorted_answer` list. What is the mistake I am making?

Comment: the sort is being applied to answer, try printing answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sorted(answer, reverse=True)
```

gives

```
[[1.7032554, 'Use the Test tools to edit'], 
[0.7578684, 'Yes, import function which lets you load items'], 
[0.58279467, 'Yes, use the Designer UI Import feature to restore content from the JSON file.']]
```

Answer (score 2):

you in place sort the list, sort return None. if you want sort return function, use sorted

```
answer.sort(key=lambda x: float(x[0]),reverse = True)
print(answer)
```

This return `None` and po assign is back to answer, thus the answer is `None` . The sort function is in place, no need to assign back

Comment: @depperm no, answer.sort() return is None, you don't need to assign back

Comment: @depperm  answer.sort() is in place !!!!!!!

Comment: @depperm agree. true